# Nested arrays in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, node.js

When I log the object right before saving it, it looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "events",
    "labels": [
        "abc",
        "123"
    ],
    "keywords": [
        [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c",
            "d",
            "e"
        ],
        [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5"
        ]
    ],
    "_id": "4d9ddac669cb3bf5e855a366"
}
```

but then if i go into the mongo shell it saves like this...

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4d9ddac669cb3bf5e855a366"),
    "keywords": [

    ],
    "labels": [
        "abc",
        "123"
    ],
    "type": "events"
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Saving that directly in the MongoDB shell keeps the nesting structure:

```
{
    "_id" : "4d9ddac669cb3bf5e855a366",
    "type" : "events",
    "labels" : [
        "abc",
        "123"
    ],
    "keywords" : [
        [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c",
            "d",
            "e"
        ],
        [
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5"
        ]
    ]
}
```

And as far as I know all the official drivers handle the nested arrays correctly.  It sounds like the BSON writer in Node may be skipping the outer array.

Can you run a few similar tests saving the same thing in the shell and with Node and see if they differ?

Comment: Inserting via the shell it works fine. I'm using Mongoose on top of Mongo within Node.